# Yii2: Create path and url for folder inside a module

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have Yii2 Advanced, and my folder structure is:

```
/frontend
- /controllers
- /models
- /modules
- - /work
- - - /controllers
- - - /models
- - - /PHOTOS
- - - /views
- /views
- /web
```

I'm putting images in the folder "/frontend/modules/work/photos".
I was wondering how do I define a variable that represents the path and url for that folder?

For example, this:

```
Yii::$app->basePath . '/uploads/';
```

Define the path to "/frontend/uploads".

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/uploads/';
```

Define the url to "frontend/web/uploads".

How do I create something identical to a folder inside the module?
"frontend/modules/work/photos" and "http:://.../frontend/work/photos"

Comment: if you have properly configured your module  as a yii2  module and declared  in you config files   (main.php) It should already be so.  You have error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the file path:
In your `common/config/bootstrap.php` file,

put this:
`Yii::setAlias('root', dirname(dirname(__DIR__));` -> path/to/your project

Then you can use `Yii::getAlias('@root/uploads/')`

About the url link:
`Url::home(true) . '/uploads/'`

Note: When configuring your domain, you specified the `path/to/frontend/web` already. For security reason, you should locate your static files (photo is in this case) within this folder only. I saw you put `frontend/web/uploads` was correct.

One of the good practice is to create a separated domain for separated upload folder `/path/to/yourapp/uploads/`. This way your web, api, backend app can share this upload folder.

Comment: But my application, "work", is inside a module ... "work" module. As I represented above, in the folder structure.

Comment: Yep. You can, and then configure your web server to accept this folder.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to set that in the alias i n config folder like:

```
Yii::setAlias('@upload_web', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/modules/work/PHOTOS');
```

after that you can retrieve that using uplod_web.